# Query Active Directory Last Logon in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, active-directory

I've been asked to retrieve the last logon for all users from active directory in a project. I am able to query their name, createaDate etc in 1 line of code but I'm not able to retrieve the lastLogon (it returns NULL)

```
Exec [dbo].[sspQueryAD] 'SELECT objectGUID,distinguishedName,objectCategory,givenName,sn,aDsPath,name,sAMAccountName,cn,objectSid,whenChanged,whenCreated 
FROM ''GC://DC=MyDC,DC=com'' 
WHERE objectclass=''user'' and objectclass <> ''computer'' or objectClass = ''organizationalUnit'' and objectclass <> ''computer'' or objectClass = ''Domain'' and objectclass <> ''computer'' or objectClass = ''Group'' and objectclass <> ''computer''', 0
```

The sspQueryAD creates the connection to AD

I've been searching for an answer but I havent been able to find any that uses SQL can anyone help me?
THANK YOU!!

Comment: You need to post the stored procedure code, your query doesn't tell us much.

Comment: I am NOT an AD guru, but it strikes me as possible that the account you're using to access AD is not permitted to see that value.  That would be something to investigate.